# brew update : fatal: unable to connect to github.com: github.com[0: 140.82.121.3]: errno=Operation timed out error

Tags: git, macos, homebrew, homebrew-cask

Facing below timeout error while updating the brew.

```
bhupendra@Bhupendras-MBP mobile-app % brew update                                        
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 140.82.121.3]: errno=Operation timed out
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 140.82.121.3]: errno=Operation timed out

Error: Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew failed!

Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core failed!
```

Please help if anyone have some solution.

Comment: Did you ever figure out this issue?

Comment: Same problem after OSX update. I tried a gazillion of "fixes" and had to switch to MacPorts after all... :(

Answer (score 6):

I fixed this issue on macOS by removing the following lines from the .gitconfig file:

```
[url "git://github.com/"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```